# Applet won't run inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, applet, jpanel

I am trying to run a Runnable class in a JPanel in a JFrame. The program compiles, but it doesnt work as intended. There should be a cube rotating on the screen, with some menus on top. What am I doing wrong? If I transform the T3D class into an applet, then the program runs just fine, it repaints, it does everything. When I try to put in a JFrame (as a Jpanel or applet) it wont repaint, it doesn't execute the stuff in init(). Thank you for your help!

**DRAWING DEMO CLASS**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class DrawingDemo extends JFrame{
public DrawingDemo()
{
T3D demo = new T3D();
getContentPane().add(demo);
setVisible(true);
setSize(1024,720);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);

T3D p = new T3D();
JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
JMenu edit = new JMenu("Edit");
JMenu settings = new JMenu("Settings");
JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem(">Exit");
JMenuItem imp = new JMenuItem(">Import");
JMenuItem exp = new JMenuItem(">Export");
JMenuItem sav = new JMenuItem(">Save");
JMenuItem ope = new JMenuItem(">Open");
file.add(ope);  
file.add(sav);
file.add(imp);
file.add(exp);
file.add(exit);
mb.add(file);
mb.add(edit);
mb.add(settings);
mb.add(help);
setJMenuBar(mb);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new DrawingDemo();
}

}
```

**3D CLASS**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

 public class T3D extends JPanel implements Runnable {
 long nextSecond = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
 int framesInLastSecond = 0;
 int framesInCurrentSecond = 0;
 int[][] LP= new int[19][3];
 double pos_camx,pos_camy,pos_camz,rot_camx,rot_camy,xpoint,ypoint,zpoint;
 double rot_radx,rot_rady,nclip,xscr,yscr,kx,ky,e;
 int pxscr,pyscr,nxscr,nyscr;

 public void start1() {
  Thread th = new Thread(this);
  th.start();

 }

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()){
    case KeyEvent.VK_A : 
    {
    pos_camx -= 0.01;
    }
    case KeyEvent.VK_D :
    {
    pos_camx += 0.01;
    }
    case KeyEvent.VK_W :
    {
    pos_camy += 0.01;
    }
    case KeyEvent.VK_S :
    {
    pos_camy -= 0.01;
    }
    } 
 }


 @Override
 public void run(){
  // This will reduce the load the applet has on the runtime
  // system..
  Thread.currentThread().setPriority(1);
  while (true) {
      e+=0.01;
      pos_camx = Math.cos(e);
      pos_camy = Math.sin(e);
      repaint();
     try {
      Thread.sleep(20);
     } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     }
  }

}

public void init() {

        LP[0][0] = -1;
        LP[0][1] = -1;
        LP[0][2] = -1;

        LP[1][0] = 1;
        LP[1][1] = -1;
        LP[1][2] = -1;

        LP[2][0] = 1;
        LP[2][1] = 1;
        LP[2][2] = -1;

        LP[3][0] = -1;
        LP[3][1] = 1;
        LP[3][2] = -1;

        LP[4][0] = -1;
        LP[4][1] = -1;
        LP[4][2] = -1;

        LP[5][0] = 1;
        LP[5][1] = 1;
        LP[5][2] = -1;

        LP[6][0] = 1;
        LP[6][1] = 1;
        LP[6][2] = 1;

        LP[7][0] = -1;
        LP[7][1] = 1;
        LP[7][2] = 1;

        LP[8][0] = -1;
        LP[8][1] = -1;
        LP[8][2] = 1;

        LP[9][0] = 1;
        LP[9][1] = -1;
        LP[9][2] = 1;

        LP[10][0] = 1;
        LP[10][1] = 1;
        LP[10][2] = 1;

        LP[11][0] = -1;
        LP[11][1] = -1;
        LP[11][2] = 1;

        LP[12][0] = -1;
        LP[12][1] = -1;
        LP[12][2] = -1;

        LP[13][0] = 1;
        LP[13][1] = -1;
        LP[13][2] = 1;

        LP[14][0] = 1;
        LP[14][1] = -1;
        LP[14][2] = -1;

        LP[15][0] = 1;
        LP[15][1] = 1;
        LP[15][2] = 1;

        LP[16][0] = -1;
        LP[16][1] = 1;
        LP[16][2] = -1;

        LP[17][0] = -1;
        LP[17][1] = 1;
        LP[17][2] = 1;

        LP[18][0] = -1;
        LP[18][1] = -1;
        LP[18][2] = -1; 


 pos_camz = 0;

 rot_camx = 0;
 rot_camy = 0;
 rot_radx = 3.1415*rot_camx/180;
 rot_rady = 3.1415*rot_camy/180;

 nclip = 0.275;
 kx = 8.52/getWidth();
 ky = 5.46/getHeight();
}

 // Drawing instructions…
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);
  Graphics2D g1 = (Graphics2D)g;
  g1.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
  g.setColor(Color.black);
     xpoint = (double)(LP[0][0])/2;
     ypoint = 10 + (double)(LP[0][1])/2;
     zpoint = (double)(LP[0][2])/2;

     pxscr = (int)(
     ((xpoint - pos_camx)*Math.cos(rot_radx) + (ypoint + pos_camy)*Math.sin(rot_radx))*nclip
     /((ypoint - pos_camy)*Math.cos(rot_radx) + (pos_camx- xpoint)*Math.sin(rot_radx) + 0.0000000012)*100/kx
                  + getWidth()/2);

     pyscr = (int)(
                  getHeight()/2-
     (((ypoint + pos_camy)*Math.sin(rot_rady) + (zpoint - pos_camz)*Math.cos(rot_rady))*nclip
     /((ypoint - pos_camy)*Math.cos(rot_radx) + (pos_camx + xpoint)*Math.sin(rot_radx) + 0.0000000012)*100/ky)
                  );
     for (int i=1; i<19;i++){
            xpoint = (double)(LP[i][0])/2;
            ypoint = 10 + (double)(LP[i][1])/2;
            zpoint = (double)(LP[i][2])/2;

            nxscr = (int)(
         ((xpoint - pos_camx)*Math.cos(rot_radx) + (ypoint + pos_camy)*Math.sin(rot_radx))*nclip
         /((ypoint - pos_camy)*Math.cos(rot_radx)+(pos_camx + xpoint)*Math.sin(rot_radx)+0.0000000012)*100/kx
                         +getWidth()/2);

            nyscr = (int)(
                         getHeight()/2-
         (((ypoint + pos_camy)*Math.sin(rot_rady)+(zpoint - pos_camz)*Math.cos(rot_rady))*nclip
         /((ypoint - pos_camy)*Math.cos(rot_radx)+(pos_camx + xpoint)*Math.sin(rot_radx)+0.0000000012)*100/ky)
                         );
            g1.drawLine(pxscr,pyscr,nxscr,nyscr);
         pxscr = nxscr;
         pyscr = nyscr;
        }
         g.drawString("(" + pxscr + "," + pyscr + ")",20,40);
         g.drawString("" + pos_camx + ")",20,60);
         g.drawString("" + pos_camy,20,80);
         g.drawString("" + rot_camx,20,100);
  long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (currentTime > nextSecond) {
    nextSecond += 1000;
    framesInLastSecond = framesInCurrentSecond;
    framesInCurrentSecond = 0;
}
    framesInCurrentSecond++;

g.drawString(framesInLastSecond + " fps", 20, 20);
}

// The standard Applet “GO” function…
public void start() {
   Thread th = new Thread(this);
  th.start();
}
}
```

Comment: What applet? Where's a class that extends Applet or JApplet? Your question and your code don't appear to be related. Please clarify.

Comment: Also note that even if you did have applet code, you generally don't run applets "in" JPanels, that an applet is a top-level window like a JFrame, and so it usually holds JPanels, not the other way around.

Comment: Well. that wasn't really helpful PS: I tried to extend Applet, but the results are the same.

Comment: You state that you are trying to run an applet inside of a JPanel and your code shows nothing of the kind. Getting you to clarify your question so it makes sense seems helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Now I think I see your problem. You've taken a class that extends JApplet and have tried to change it into a JPanel leaving the init() method and all intact. Swing doesn't work that way. You will need to re-write the JApplet type class, get rid of applet specific methods such as init() and start() and instead likely initialize that code in the class's constructor. You'll want to read up on how do graphics and animation in Swing -- using a JPanel's paintComponent method for instance, and a Swing Timer, and this way will likely succeed.